Residue of inverse function using Lagrange inversion
Let $v(z)$ be an infinite power series of terms $z^k$ where $k>0$ with coefficients $v_k$ and an analytic function except at $z=0$, and $V(z)$ be the inverse of $v(z)$, then show that $\operatorname{Res}_0(V(z)^{-k})=k\times v_k$ at $z=0$ using Lagrange inversion, could you also extend for any other arbitrary singularity $z_0$ rather than $z=0$.

? What have you tried? Also, there a few variations on the theme of "Lagrange inversion". Which one are you using? This needs a bit more deth to it, as a question

I have tried Lagrange burmann formula,but I can't prove this residue formula.I am having difficulty figuring it out.

Suggestion. It is conceptually cleaner for computational manipulations to represent the analytic map's input  and output variables by distinct letters.  Write  $w= f(z)$ and the inverse relation as  $z= g(w)$.
Then use the integral representation of the residue $$Res[g(w)^{-k},w=0] =\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint _{w\in C}  \frac{ dw}{g^k(w)}$$
This can be evaluated by changing variables so that $g(w)=z$ , then using the substitution $ dw = f'(z) dz$ and expanding that derivative $f'(z)$ in its Taylor expansion in powers of $z$, etc.
P.S. One technical detail: note that  the small contour $C$ about $w=0$ is transformed bijectively  into  some new small contour $C'$  about $z=0$ that has the same orientation as that of $C$.

What would happen if V(a)=0 .
